# In Gnosis Safe, Is there any information about transaction service's API Spec detail?

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis

I want to use the public Transaction Service operated by Gnosis Safe. You can find out how to use the API through Swag [here](https://docs.safe.global/learn/safe-core/safe-core-api/available-services), but details such as rate limit or ban policy are not available.

There seems to be no special settings in Gnosis Safe's Gateway code. Do you have a Rate Limit or Ban policy for Public Transaction Service? If it exists, what are the details?

Comment: its 5req per sec